# Inserting a key value in a map where value of map is a vector pair

Tags: c++

I've a hard time to figure out how to insert an element in this following type of map. Given:

```
std::map<Node*, std::vector<pair<Edge*, Node*> > > adjacencyMap;
```

,where `Node` and `Edge` are structs. I want to create a graph and each connection between two nodes should be stored in this map. Each node could have more than one connection to another node. The main idea is that for each node there could be a list of pairs of edges and nodes, e.g.

```
node1 and node2 are connected through an edge12
node1 and node3 are connected through an edge13
```

The `adjacencyMap` should like

```
node1 -> [(edge12, node2), (edge13, node3)]
node2 -> [(edge12, node1)]
node3 -> [(edge13, node1)]
```

I know how to insert an element like `(node1, pair(edge12,node2))` but I don't know how to insert, if `(node1, pair(edge12,node2))` is already an element, `(node1, pair(edge13, node3))` sucht that

```
node1 -> [(edge12, node2), (edge13, node3)].
```

How can I realize my intention?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful when using pointers as the keys in a map, as it's the pointers themselves that will be the key and not the objects they point to.

Comment: If the graph has many edges a better data structure may be an adjacency matrix. `O(1)` for inserting nodes.

Comment: The graph will not contain more than 50 nodes and each node should not have more than two edges.

Comment: @aGer I would go for adjecency matrix then - more compact representation, faster operations, cache friendlier.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I've considered this option, but I do not know how to store the "edge between to nodes" - information in my matrix.

Comment: @aGer See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_matrix.html for inspiration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that memory management for `Node` and `Edge` is somewhere else since storing raw pointers implies that nobody will take care of their management.

`operator[]` of `std::unordered_map` already constructs a default value if it was not present so acually it's enough to just push them:

```
map[node1].emplace_back(edge13, node2);
map[node1].emplace_back(edge13, node3);
```

Comment: I would advise to store a reference to the vector instead, as each of these calls is O(ln(n)).

Comment: That's definitely a good micro optimization but it depends if OP code needs to store them all at once or not.

Comment: Ah, this looks nice. I've tried something like this 
´auto vectorList = adjmap[node1]; vectorList.push_back(std::make_pair(edge12, &node2));´ But this didn't work well because inserting ´(node1, pair(edge13,node3))´ resulted in ´node1 -> [(edge13, node3)]´

Comment: @aGer: `vectorList` was a copy so your push back had no effect on the original object (can't explain your stated results though). It should have been `auto& vectorList`

Comment: Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I would use `emplace_back` to get rid of `make_pair`.

Answer (score 2):

You might do:

```
adjacencyMap[node1] = {{edge12, node2}, {edge13, node3}};
adjacencyMap[node2] = {{edge12, node1}};
adjacencyMap[node3] = {{edge13, node1}};
```

or even:

```
std::map<Node*, std::vector<std::pair<Edge*, Node*>>> adjacencyMap =
{
    {node1, {{edge12, node2}, {edge13, node3}}},
    {node2, {{edge12, node1}}},
    {node3, {{edge13, node1}}}
};
```

To add nodes, you might do:

```
// use alias to avoid several look-up
auto& v1 = adjacencyMap[node1]; // auto is std::vector<std::pair<Edge*, Node*>>>
// Then do job on the vector:
v1.emplace_back(edge12, node2);
v1.emplace_back(edge13, node3);
```

Comment: I don't really know how many nodes and edges will be inserted at compile time.

Comment: So the `might do` is the way to go.